# Get an id of a 'a' element with bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to get the id of an element. I'm using the table of bootstrap to display a list of data from my database. When a user click on a line, I want to redirect the user to an other page.

This is the declaration of my table :

```
while ($data = pg_fetch_array($res))
{       
   echo' <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a id="'.$data['id_essai'].'"> //This is the id that I want to get !!
                        '.$data['id_essai'].'
                    </a></td>
                    <td>
                        '.$data['nom_local_essai'].'
                    </td>           
                    <td>
                        '.$data['thematique'].'
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>                    
        ';
}
```

And I use this function which happens when the user click on a line :

```
 $('table').on('click', 'tr' , function (event) {
        console.log($('a').attr('id'));      
 });
```

And I don't know how to get the `attr` id of my `a`. So I tried `$('a').attr('id')` but it doesn't work.

Some help please !

Comment: Try this..$(this).find('a').attr('id');

Comment: It works, thanks !! :)

Comment: I'll post as answer..

Comment: HTML is very semantical. You should add the `id` to the row (`<tr>`), not to the link `<a>`. Because the whole row represents a dataset by id, not only a link inside a column. DavidG's suggestion is good, `data-` attributes are better way. Tho it doesn't directly solve the problem.

Comment: @DanFromGermany Ok, I made what you did, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the anchor tag inside the clicked `tr` using 
    `$(this).find('a')`

Now `$(this).find('a').attr('id')` will get you the id

```
  $('table').on('click', 'tr' , function (event) {
       console.log($(this).find('a').attr('id'););
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

the "a" you want to get the id of, is not specified enough so it is looking for the id of any a tag. You need to ask for the attribute of the 'a' in the 'tr' you clicked.

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr' , function (event) {
    console.log($('a', this).attr('id'));

});
```

or

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr' , function (event) {
    console.log($(this).find('a').attr('id'));

});
```